# How to use a RKValueTransformer to convert a NSString to a Core Data NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I'm getting a string back from a server, and I need to convert it into a State object, which is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.  The transformer works fine, except that I don't know what the `ManagedObjectContext` is at the time of the mapping, so I get the error `illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'state' between objects in different contexts`.

`RKEntityMapping` knows how to automatically create the proper object during the mapping operation, so the functionality is within RestKit.  How can I create this core data object properly?

```
RKValueTransformer *stateTransformer = [RKBlockValueTransformer valueTransformerWithValidationBlock:^BOOL(__unsafe_unretained Class sourceClass, __unsafe_unretained Class destinationClass) {
    return ([sourceClass isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]] && [destinationClass isSubclassOfClass:[State class]]);
} transformationBlock:^BOOL(id inputValue, __autoreleasing id *outputValue, Class outputValueClass, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {
    // Validate the input and output
    RKValueTransformerTestInputValueIsKindOfClass(inputValue, [NSString class], error);
    RKValueTransformerTestOutputValueClassIsSubclassOfClass(outputValueClass, [State class], error);

    State *state = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"State" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

    state.abbreviation = inputValue;

    *outputValue = state;

    return YES;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating your state object and setting the string into a single attribute on the object. To do this you don't need a custom transformer, you just need to use a nil key path mapping.

See the `Mapping Values without Key Paths` section of [the Object-mapping wiki page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).